# can I use a keystore generated by java keytool in a different jre implementation

Tags: java, encryption, aes

I want to encode/decode a string in two different java environment and those enviroments use different jre implementations. Can I use a keystore generated in IBM jre implementation, in oracle jre implementation ?

Comment: This is old, but might give some clues: https://community.oracle.com/thread/1534230

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use it keystore in any Java environment. I have one key for to sign my Android app on Mac, then use it on PC to make changes and on my Android phone too when I use my app. It is universal.